# Is it safe to use a fork from pub.dev repository in a flutter project?

Tags: flutter, dart, github

Lets say I am using a specific package 'x' and I need to update something or fix an issue but the authors are not approving new PRs or fixing issues anymore.

So, I want to to fork the repo and use my new version or even someone else's fork like this for example (pubspec.yaml):

```
  x:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/username/x.git
      ref: branch_name
```

My question is, is it safe to do this? What happens if the branch gets deleted or the github account itself? Can this cause any problem on the stability of my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, is it safe to do this? What happens if the branch gets deleted or the github account itself?

If it's *your* fork, then that's entirely under your control.

If it's someone else's Git repository, then yes, quite obviously your project would have a broken dependency when that dependency requires a Git repository that is on longer accessible.

> Can this cause any problem on the stability of my project?

Depends.  If you're referencing a *branch* on someone else's Git repository, then when that branch is updated with additional commits, when you eventually run `dart pub get`/`flutter pub get` in your project, you'll automatically pull in those commits, whether you want them or not.  Will any of those commits have breaking changes?  Since you'd no longer be using [semantic versioning](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/versioning#semantic-versions), who knows.

But again, if you're referencing your own Git repository, then that repository is entirely under your control.

Note that using a Git dependency also could lead to version conflicts since `pub` would be required to use the specified commit and would no longer be able to consider semantically compatible versions of that package.

Bottom line:

- If you're referencing someone else's Git repository, you probably should reference specific commits via tags or commit hashes, not via branch names.  Even then, there's a risk of the repository being deleted.
- If you're referencing your own Git repository, everything is under your own control.  Note that if you don't care about sharing it with others, you also could add a local copy to your Dart/Flutter project and [refer to it via a local path](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#path-packages).
- Using non-versioned package dependencies could make version conflicts more likely.